# How to compare values in the same python dictionary and do stuff if match

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, dictionary

I have a dictionary such as :

```
{
     "number_1":
    {
        "month_year": "5/2022",
        "price": 1,
        "average": 1,
        "covered": 1,
    },
    "number_2":
    {
        "month_year": "5/2022",
        "price": 1,
        "average": 1,
        "covered": 1,
    },
    "number_3":
    {
        "month_year": "4/2022",
        "price": 10,
        "average": 93,
        "covered": 100,
    },
    "number_4":
    {
        "month_year": "4/2022",
        "price": 10,
        "average": 93,
        "covered": 100,
    },
}
```

I need a `generic` way to get the total of values if dictionaries has the same value for the key `month_year` so for example for `month_year` `5/2022` it's gonna be :

```
{
    "month_year": "5/2022",
    "total_price": 2,
    "total_average": 2,
    "total_covered": 2,
}
```

Comment: This dictionary does not look correctly formatted from python perspective as all sub-dict should have a key as well. Else it will likely return error - unhashable type

Comment: @Pankaj True thanks it's edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the existing answers are either too complicated, or not generic enough. This should work for all new fields (assuming they're still numeric), and relies on builtin `collections` to do most of the heavy lifting.

```py
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def group(mappings):
    dict_by_date = defaultdict(Counter)
    for mapping in mappings.values():
        date = mapping["month_year"]
        fields = {k: v for k, v in mapping.items() if k != "month_year"}
        dict_by_date[date].update(fields)
    return [{"month_year": date, **fields} for date, fields in dict_by_date.items()]
```

Result for the example:

```py
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(group(test))
[{'average': 2, 'covered': 2, 'month_year': '5/2022', 'price': 2},
 {'average': 186, 'covered': 200, 'month_year': '4/2022', 'price': 20}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group all elements `d` which have the same `d['month_year']` value, using a `dict` with `d['month_year']` as the keys.

```py
data = {
     "number_1":
    {"month_year": "5/2022", "price": 1, "average": 1, "covered": 1},
    "number_2":
    {"month_year": "5/2022", "price": 1, "average": 1, "covered": 1},
    "number_3":
    {"month_year": "4/2022", "price": 10, "average": 93, "covered": 100},
    "number_4":
    {"month_year": "4/2022", "price": 10, "average": 93, "covered": 100},
}

result = {}
for d in data.values():
    if d['month_year'] in result:
        for k in ('price', 'average', 'covered'):
            result[d['month_year']][k] += d[k]
    else:
        result[d['month_year']] = dict(d)

print(result)
# {'5/2022': {'month_year': '5/2022', 'covered': 2, 'price': 2, 'average': 2},
#  '4/2022': {'month_year': '4/2022', 'covered': 200, 'price': 20, 'average': 186}}
```

Comment: Stef, this also somehow changes the source dictionary too. If feasible, can you please share why and perhaps something that might avoid same. Though for this question I think it does answers.

Comment: @Pankaj You're right. it's because I wrote `result[d['month_year']] = d` instead of `result[d['month_year']] = dict(d)`, so the original dicts are used, instead of a copy. I edited to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Like other answers you may have already seen, your dictionary is not formatted correctly. Because your sub-dictionaries are inside a dictionary, you must give them a key as well. Here is an example:

```
{
    "1st Dictionary": {
        "month_year": "5/2022",
        "price": 1,
        "average": 1,
        "covered": 1,
    },
    "2nd Dictionary": {
        "month_year": "5/2022",
        "price": 1,
        "average": 1,
        "covered": 1,
    },
    "3rd Dictionary": {
        "month_year": "4/2022",
        "price": 10,
        "average": 93,
        "covered": 100,
    },
    "4th Dictionary": {
        "month_year": "4/2022",
        "price": 10,
        "average": 93,
        "covered": 100,
    },
}
```

Here you are giving each sub-dictionary a key. Each key simply states which dictionary in the dictionary of dictionaries it is. Here is an alternative method:

```
{
    0: {
        "month_year": "5/2022",
        "price": 1,
        "average": 1,
        "covered": 1,
    },
    1: {
        "month_year": "5/2022",
        "price": 1,
        "average": 1,
        "covered": 1,
    },
    2: {
        "month_year": "4/2022",
        "price": 10,
        "average": 93,
        "covered": 100,
    },
    3: {
        "month_year": "4/2022",
        "price": 10,
        "average": 93,
        "covered": 100,
    },
}
```

This is the same thing except you are using numbers 0-3. This may be a better idea because this way you are giving a key similar to an index.

Now back to your question! If you wanted to get a certain index of either of these dictionaries, you would first have to define a variable with said dictionary, and then type the key inside brackets next to the variable (similar to a list). For simplicity, I will use the first dictionary. Here is what I’m talking about:

```
dictionary={
    "1st Dictionary": {
        "month_year": "5/2022",
        "price": 1,
        "average": 1,
        "covered": 1,
    },
    "2nd Dictionary": {
        "month_year": "5/2022",
        "price": 1,
        "average": 1,
        "covered": 1,
    },
    "3rd Dictionary": {
        "month_year": "4/2022",
        "price": 10,
        "average": 93,
        "covered": 100,
    },
    "4th Dictionary": {
        "month_year": "4/2022",
        "price": 10,
        "average": 93,
        "covered": 100,
    },
}

if dictionary["1st Dictionary"]["price"]>1:
    print("if statement ran successfully!")

elif dictionary["1st Dictionary"]["price"]==1:
    print("elif statement ran successfully!")
```

Here, the output is: elif statement ran successfully!

What we are doing here is getting the key named `“1st Dictionary”` and then the key named `“price”` inside of said dictionary. Here is an example of this behavior with lists:

```
my_list=[
    [1,2,3],
    ["a","b","c"],
    [0.1,0.2,0.3]
]

if my_list[0][1]==2:
    print("if statement ran successfully!")
```

If we run this code, we get the output: if statement ran successfully!

Here we are checking if the second index inside of the first list inside of `my_list` is equal to 2. Just for clarification, here you can see that the first index of `my_list` is `[1,2,3]`, and that the second index of the first index of `my_list` is 2.

```
my_list[0]==[1,2,3]

my_list[0][1]==2
```

Hopefully this answered your question in a simple and easy-to-understand way!

Comment: yes true it's edited

Comment: Now that you’ve changed it, a lot of what a typed is redundant (which is fine!) but did I still answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution
If you have similar adjacent keys else try @steff solution

**#Assuming you have list of dictionaries bcz set of dictionaries is not possible due to unhashable type dicts**

```
a = [{"month_year": "5/2022","price": 1,"average": 1,"covered": 1,
    },{"month_year": "5/2022","price": 1,"average": 1,"covered": 1,},{"month_year": "4/2022","price": 10,"average": 93,"covered": 100,},{"month_year": "4/2022","price": 10,"average": 93,"covered": 100,},]

from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

a.sort(key=lambda x: x["month_year"]) # We need to do this because groupby needs data in sorted manner
print([ {**sum((Counter(vals) for vals in val if (_:=vals.pop("month_year")) and (not print(vals))), Counter()), **{"month_year": key}} for key, val in groupby(a, key=lambda x: x["month_year"])])

# output [{'price': 20, 'average': 186, 'covered': 200, 'month_year': '4/2022'}, {'price': 2, 'average': 2, 'covered': 2, 'month_year': '5/2022'}]
```

Explanation: First groupby with keys `month_year` we get unique key of month_year and list of values of that group where we applied (sum of two dictionaries using `Counter`) and then put back my key in the resultant dictionary.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` only groups adjacent elements. You need to group manually instead, using a dict.

Comment: @Stef No you can try it without adjacent elements it will work. You need to specify the key with which you want to group by. That key needs to be present in each value of list. The above code will work for your use case as well.

Comment: It looks like you edited one minute ago, and now I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when I try your code. But I assure you that `groupby` only groups adjacent elements. If you change the order of the four elements in the list, so that the two `"5/2022"` are not adjacent, then groupby will not group them together.

Comment: you got syntax error may be for `walrus operator` because you are not using latest python version. Just try it on online python editor. Also I have just removed whitespaces while editing the code.

Comment: @Stef now it should work.